# Append string to url based on condition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, href

I'm trying to figure out how to add either `?ref=xyz` or `&ref=xyz` depending on whether a question mark is already part of the url (`?ref=xyz` if no ? is present, or `&ref=xyz` if there is a ? in the URL)

Here's what I'm trying to do without success, can anyone help me write code that will test for both conditions and append the appropriate string to the end of the URL please?

```
$('a[href*="domainname"]').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    if([doesn't contain ?]) {
        return attr + '?ref=xyz';
    } else if([contains ?]) {
        return attr + '&ref=xyz';
    }
});
```

Thanks,

Osu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indexOf` JavaScript method. Try this.

```
$('a[href*="domainname"]').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    if(attr.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        return attr + '?ref=xyz';
    } else{
        return attr + '&ref=xyz';
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, I just neeed to update the second part of the expression, works a treat. Need to wait 9 mins to approve the answer, but thank you!

Comment: @Osu - Edited my answer, else part doesn't need any condition.